# Vue js not rendering VdtnetTable. What might be the issue

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7, laravel-vue, vue-data-tables

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

found in

---> <VdtnetTable>
       <App> at resources/js/kodie/properties/Table.vue
         <Properties> at resources/js/kodie/properties/index.vue
           <Root>
```

I have tried to install npm run several times. I have been using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-datatables-net to clone datatable to my vue js.
all the time I am getting the error below. does no

Comment: Please check the vue version you are using this data table library is for vue3 and you might be using vue2

Comment: It is also supported in vue 2. I just had to downgrade by running npm i vue-datatables-net@1.4.0 a lower version.

Answer (score 0):

`vue-datatables-net` are also supported in vue2.
I had to degrade the package to a lower version i.e `npm i vue-datatables-net@1.4.0`.

Here is the link to the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-datatables-net/v/1.4.0